# Trying to get R gsub Regex to work with PHP preg_replace Regex

Tags: php, regex, json, r

You'll have to forgive me as I am really bad at regex.

So here is what I'm trying to do. I'm working on pulling Option Chains from Google Finance's API. The only problem is Google doesn't  wrap the JSON keys in quotes like they should be. I found a method of using a replace string method with a regex but it is in R and I'm working with PHP.

The JSON I'm working with is from [here](https://www.google.com/finance/option_chain?q=NYSE:LUV&expd=20&expm=2&expy=2015&output=json)

**R:**

```
gsub('([^,{:]+):', '"\1":', json)
```

**PHP:**

```
$pattern = '([^,{:]+):';
$replacement = '"\1":';
$json = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $quote);
```

I tried the PHP code seen above and I'm getting:

```
[18-Jan-2015 21:34:36 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Unknown modifier ':' in /home1/oldpizza/public_html/austingregory/stocks/index.php on line 10
```

I'm betting it is the difference between PHP and R regex patterns but I'm not sure about the difference as I am still very new to regex in general. But according to [regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/dH3hL5/1) it should work...
Not quite sure where to go from there. If you could help me out with the regex or help me figure out why it isn't working that would be great.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delimiter is required in `preg_replace`:

```
$pattern = '~([^,{:]+):~';
$replacement = '"\1":';
$json = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $quote);
```

`/`, `~` and `#` are usually used as delimiter, but `()` pair can also be used as delimiter, and that is the reason why you got the warning above. It is interpreting the outermost pair of `()` as delimiter, and `:` at the end as modifier (flag).